# Can Webpack helps me separate a large single file into smaller pieces?

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundle, vendor

use `.js` files as example:
To reduce the number of requests, I know `Webpack` can concatenate and compress multiple javascript files into a single file,
but, what if a single source of my javascript file has already tooooo large for a single request? maybe 10MB or larger.
By the way, I don't want to separate it by myself.

Can `Webpack` helps me separate a large single file into smaller pieces?

for example, if I pass `3` into whatever how it works,
the `big.js` will separate into `small-1.js`, `small-2.js`, `small-3.js`,
something like this

I'm a beginner of `Webpack`, I just want to know what `Webpack` can or cannot do.
thanks

Comment: I believe parcel.js developers are working on something similar: splitting with no configuration. [Parcel](https://parceljs.org/) is a new webpack alternative focused on being faster and easyer.

Comment: No, webpack cannot split an existing js file into small js files. What does your 10MB file do? That seems extremely large.

Comment: I totally have no idea what the 10MB file do... but I know if our website with it, everything works fine, without it, everything's going down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To reduce the number of requests, I know Webpack can concatenate and
>   compress multiple javascript files into a single file,

Web pack can combine existing files and minify them. Minification is not compression. It just removes whitespace and shortens variable names. This can make a js file smaller but not significantly.

> but, what if a single source of my javascript file has already tooooo
>   large for a single request? maybe 10MB or larger. By the way, I don't
>   want to separate it by myself.
>
> Can Webpack helps me separate a large single file into smaller pieces?

No web pack can't do this. Minification might make a file smaller but not significantly. Web pack also cannot split a large file into small files. It can be built to combine files together in such a way that the assests are smaller (see https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/) but it has no way to take one large file and to produce lots of smaller files from this one file.

Your only option is to refactor yout large file into a smaller one. 10Mb seems huge! What on earth is this doing? This is the nub of your problem. Why is this so large how can you make it smaller. There is no magic bullet here.

> I'm a beginner of Webpack, I just want to know what Webpack can or
>   cannot do.

Tl;Dr **No you cannot**

Comment: thanks for answering. The file will be that big 'cause it's a history burden.. we lost the source files of this concatenated & shortened names file. It's hard to read/refactored

Comment: I guess the only thing I can do is figure out  what features this file has and recreate it. then hope every thing will be fine.